# flutter More than one file was found with OS independent path 'AndroidManifest.xml'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I have a sample flutter project that has multiple lib modules that can build with

```
./gradlew app:assembleDevRelease
```

but for some reason when I run

```
flutter run --release --flavor dev
```

It is trying to run

```
./gradlew assembleDevRelease
```

command that of project level, then I got the error

```
> Task :track_sdk_plugin:mergeDevReleaseJavaResource FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':track_sdk_plugin:mergeDevReleaseJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'AndroidManifest.xml'
```

Any idea why this is not working? Can provide the gradle file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there were more than two `AndroidManifest.xml` files in one of the modules due to migrating from the old project.

Please search for the `AndroidManifest.xml` files under your project directory, if you could find there were more than one in `src` folder, only keep the one in `src/main` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case with the following error message:

```
More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libswscale.so'.
```

The problem was that I accidentally had both the following dependencies in my `pubspec.yaml`:

- `ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl: ^4.5.0`
- `ffmpeg_kit_flutter: ^4.5.0-LTS`

The top one of course has everything that the below one has and that caused the issue. The below one was unnecessary.